# Satis can read composer.json, but cannot checkout the other files

Tags: php, svn, composer-php, visualsvn-server, satis

After trying Satis on my personnal SVN server (Linux, Svn, Apache 2, SSL, LDAP, DAV), that works fine; I am trying to make it work on my company's SVN server (Windows, Visual SVN, SSL).

In both cases Satis runs under Linux; Mine is an Ubuntu, and my company's is a CentOs.

On my company's Satis instance, it can browse the repository, it can get the composer.json of the project, but it won't get the project itself, at the same level than the composer.json.

Here is an anonymized version of the satis.json :

```
{
    "name": "MyCompany",
    "homepage": "http://my-server.net/satis",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "svn",
            "url": "https://my-other-server.net/svn/my-project"
        }
    ],
    "config": {
        "http-basic": {
            "my-other-server.net": {
                "username": "my-readonly-username",
                "password": "my-readonly-password"
            }
        }
    },
    "archive": {
        "directory": "dist",
        "format": "tar",
        "prefix-url": "http://my-server.net/satis/"
    },
    "require-all": true
}
```

Here is an anonymized version on the project's composer.json :

```
{
    "name": "mycompany/project",
    "type": "symfony-bundle",
    "description": "Project 1.0",
    "keywords": [ "project" ],
    "homepage": "http://my-company.fr/project",
    "licence": "proprietary",
    "version": "1.0",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "My team",
            "email": "address@inter.net"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4"
    },
    "autoload": {
            "psr-4": { "Mycompany\\ProjectBundle\\": "" }
    }
}
```

Here is how i execute Satis :

```
php bin/satis build mycompany.json web -vvv
```

And finaly, here is the anonymized verbose result of Satis :

```
Executing command (CWD): git describe --exact-match --tags
Executing command (CWD): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (CWD): hg branch
Executing command (CWD): svn info --xml
Failed to initialize global composer: Composer could not find the config file: /root/.composer/composer.json
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the http://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
Scanning packages
Executing command (CWD): svn ls --verbose --non-interactive  --username 'my-readonly-username' --password 'my-readonly-password'  'https://my-other-server.net/svn/my-project/trunk'
Executing command (CWD): svn ls --verbose --non-interactive  --username 'my-readonly-username' --password 'my-readonly-password'  'https://my-other-server.net/svn/my-project/branches'
Executing command (CWD): svn ls --verbose --non-interactive  --username 'my-readonly-username' --password 'my-readonly-password'  'https://my-other-server.net/svn/my-project/tags'
Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---my-other-server.net-svn-my-project/-trunk--4-.json from cache
Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---my-other-server.net-svn-my-project/-trunk--4-.json from cache
Reading composer.json of mycompany/project (trunk)
Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---my-other-server.net-svn-my-project/-trunk--4-.json from cache
Importing branch trunk (dev-trunk)
Selected mycompany/project (dev-trunk)
Creating local downloads in 'web/dist'
Dumping 'mycompany/project-9999999-dev'.
  - Installing mycompany/project (dev-trunk)
    Checking out /trunk/@4
Failed: [RuntimeException] Package could not be downloaded, svn: OPTIONS de 'https://my-other-server.net/svn/project/trunk': Échec à l'autorisation (https://my-other-server.net)
```

[RuntimeException]
      Package could not be downloaded, svn: OPTIONS de 'https://my-other-server.net/svn/project/trunk': Échec à l'autorisation (https://my-other-server.net)

```
Exception trace:
 () at /srv/satis/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Downloader/SvnDownloader.php:91
 Composer\Downloader\SvnDownloader->execute() at /srv/satis/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Downloader/SvnDownloader.php:33
 Composer\Downloader\SvnDownloader->doDownload() at /srv/satis/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Downloader/VcsDownloader.php:66
 Composer\Downloader\VcsDownloader->download() at /srv/satis/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Downloader/DownloadManager.php:201
 Composer\Downloader\DownloadManager->download() at /srv/satis/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Package/Archiver/ArchiveManager.php:144
 Composer\Package\Archiver\ArchiveManager->archive() at /srv/satis/src/Composer/Satis/Command/BuildCommand.php:410
 Composer\Satis\Command\BuildCommand->dumpDownloads() at /srv/satis/src/Composer/Satis/Command/BuildCommand.php:159
 Composer\Satis\Command\BuildCommand->execute() at /srv/satis/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:253
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /srv/satis/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:874
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /srv/satis/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:195
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /srv/satis/src/Composer/Satis/Console/Application.php:52
 Composer\Satis\Console\Application->doRun() at /srv/satis/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /srv/satis/bin/satis:9

build [--no-html-output] [--skip-errors] [file] [output-dir] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

Other elements :

- While debugging, i am root on the Satis server, as when i execute it
- I have tried to rm -rf /root/.composer
- I have tried to give full rights to my-readonly-username on Visual SVN
- I have tried to drink more cofee

None of this changed anything (except maybe the coffee).

Comment: I tried to copy the repository definition and authentication parameters from my company's Satis to my personnal Satis, and it works. So the problem doesn't come from the Visual SVN part, but from the system (Centos 5.9), SVN client (1.6.11) or Satis.

Comment: It looks like the satis server can not access the SVN server.  There is probably some firewall or something that needs to whitelist your satis server.  Can you manually checkout an SVN repo from the satis server?

Comment: Yes, without problem. Like i wrote, Satis can checkout the composer.json of the project. But not the whole folder.

Comment: If you are quite sure that communication with the SVN server in general is not an issue, I would guess that satis is not correctly passing your auth credentials in some cases.  Did your personal SVN server have similar auth configuration to your company's?  When I set up satis for a private company, it was pointing to a private github account.  I had to dig into the satis code to discover an undocumented configuration option to get it to work.  You may have to go to similar extremes to solve your problem.

Comment: When i use my own Satis, i run it interactively, and it asks me for my credentials. When i use the one i made for my company, there is a dedicated account used by jenkins, sonar, deploy scripts etc. So the credentials are saved in the json file. The most curious thing is that it can read the composer.json file of the project ... Anyway thank you, i will check that part when back at the office tomorrow.